# Proper Threading Technique in C# (using Timer + Receive Handler + BackgroundWorker)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to threading, and I am trying to use it in a program (front end for a hardware test), but running into heavy time delays - clearly I'm doing something wrong.

**My Setup:**

I have a hardware controller hooked up to my PC. I am communicating with it via serial to read values from 4 sensors. This communication sits within receiveHandler,

```
private void receiveHandler(object sender, DataStreamEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] dataBytes = e.Response;
    //throws it into a string
    //parses the string with delimiters
    //adds all items to a linked-list "queue"
}
```

I have a timer (System.Timers.Timer) that will count the duration of the hardware test, do one calculation and ask the controller for the updated state of each sensor.

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test.duration = ++tickCounter;
    test.ampHoursOut = (test.ampHoursOut * 3600 + test.amperage * 1) / 3600;
    sendToController("CH2.GETANALOG"); //repeat this line once for each sensor
}
```

I currently have a BackgroundWorker that will take the data collected from the controller (that I stuck in a "queue" in receiveHandler) and comprehend it  + do some calculations + update the UI.

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        //do a whole lot of logic
    }
}
```

**My Problem:**

One of my controller inputs is reading the state of a hardware switch. I notice that there is a 5 second delay between when I hit the switch and when it's state changes on the UI.

There must be a heavy delay in my processing. I imagine BackgroundWorker isn't catching up with all of the information coming in. I'm asking for information every second (via the timer), so maybe this needs to slow down - but I would like to have information update every second to have an accurate test.

Am I using the timer, backgroundworker, and receive handler correctly? What can be done to speed up my communication + processing?

I'm a self-taught programmer and don't necessarily (as you can probably see) know all of the basic concepts. Any advice would be appreciated :)

Thanks, Julia

**EDIT:** Code:

```
    //variables used (added relevant ones so code is better understood)      
    private static System.Timers.Timer timer;
    LinkedList<string> incomingData = new LinkedList<string>();
    string lastDatum = "";


    /// <summary>
    /// Method that is called when serial data is received from the controller.
    /// The data is received in bytes, converted to a string and parsed at each "::" which represents a new message.
    /// The last 'item' from the data is saved and added to the front of the next set of data, in case it is incomplete.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void receiveHandler(object sender, DataStreamEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] dataBytes = e.Response;
        string data = lastDatum + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(dataBytes); // reads the next available line coming from the serial port
        UpdateDataTextbox(data);  // prints it out for debuging purposes

        lastDatum = ""; // just in case

        char[] delimiters = new char[] { ':' }; // splits the data at the ":" symbol, deleting empty entries.
        Queue<string> dataQueue = new Queue<string>(data.Split(delimiters,
                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        while(dataQueue.Count > 1)
        {
            string str = dataQueue.Dequeue().Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace(":", string.Empty).Trim(); // remove all useless characters
            if (str != "")
            {
                incomingData.AddLast(str); // add to a queue that can be accessed by the background worker for processing & outputting.
            }
        }
        lastDatum = dataQueue.Dequeue(); // Last data item in a transmission may be incomplete "CH1.GETDA" and thus it is appended to the front of the next list of data.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Background Worker thread will be used to continue testing the connection to the controller,
    /// process messages in the incoming message queue (actually a linked list),
    /// and sends new messages for updated data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        while (!worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            if (!relayBoard.OpenConn())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection to controller has been lost.");
                testInterrupted = "Lost connection. Time = " + test.duration;
                UpdateStatusText(false);
                ShutErDown();
            }

            //update test time & Ah out
            timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tickCounter);
            UpdateDurationTextbox(timeSpan.ToString()); // update display with duration
            UpdateAhTextbox(test.ampHoursOut.ToString());

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (incomingData.Count > 0)
            {
                string dataLine = "";
                try
                {
                    dataLine = incomingData.First();
                }
                catch (System.InvalidOperationException emai)
                {
                    break; //data hasn't come in yet, it will by the time this runs next.
                }

                incomingData.RemoveFirst();

                if (dataLine.Contains("GET"))  // some sensor values (analog/temp/digital) has come in
                {
                    if (dataLine.Contains("GETANALOG")) // an analog value has come in
                    {
                        int index = dataLine.IndexOf("CH");
                        int pin = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(dataLine[index + 2]);

                        double value = 0;
                        int dataLineLength = dataLine.Length;
                        if (dataLineLength > 13) // value is appended to end of line
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                value = Convert.ToDouble(dataLine.Substring(13));
                            }
                            catch // can't convert to double
                            {
                                int index2 = dataLine.IndexOf("CH", 3);
                                if (index2 != -1) // there happen to be two sets of commands stuck together into one
                                {
                                    string secondHalf = dataLine.Substring(index2);
                                    incomingData.AddFirst(secondHalf);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else // value is on the next line
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                value = Convert.ToDouble(incomingData.First());
                                incomingData.RemoveFirst();
                            }
                            catch // can't convert to double
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Error occured: " + dataLine);
                            }
                        }
                        switch (pin)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                ReadVoltage(value);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                ReadAmperage(value);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (dataLine.Contains("GETTEMP")) // received reply with temperature data
                    {
                        int index = dataLine.IndexOf("CH");
                        int pin = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(dataLine[index + 2]); // using index of CH, retrieve which pin this message is coming from

                        double value = 0;
                        int dataLineLength = dataLine.Length;
                        if (dataLineLength > 11) // value is appended to end of line
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                value = Convert.ToDouble(dataLine.Substring(11));
                            }
                            catch // can't convert to double
                            {
                                int index2 = dataLine.IndexOf("CH", 3);
                                if (index2 != -1) // there happen to be two sets of commands stuck together into one
                                {
                                    string secondHalf = dataLine.Substring(index2);
                                    incomingData.AddFirst(secondHalf);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else // value is on the next line
                        {
                            value = Convert.ToDouble(incomingData.First());
                            incomingData.RemoveFirst();
                        }
                        ReadTemperature(pin, value);
                    }
                    else // must be CH3.GET
                    {
                        int index = dataLine.IndexOf("CH");
                        int pin = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(dataLine[index + 2]); // using index of CH, retrieve which pin this message is coming from

                        if (pin == 3) // only care if it's pin 3 (BMS), otherwise it's a mistake
                        {
                            double value = 0;
                            int dataLineLength = dataLine.Length;
                            if (dataLineLength > 7) // value is appended to end of line
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    value = Convert.ToDouble(dataLine.Substring(7));
                                }
                                catch // can't convert to double
                                {
                                    int index2 = dataLine.IndexOf("CH", 3);
                                    if (index2 != -1) // there happen to be two sets of commands stuck together into one
                                    {
                                        string secondHalf = dataLine.Substring(index2);
                                        incomingData.AddFirst(secondHalf);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else // value is on the next line
                            {
                                value = Convert.ToDouble(incomingData.First());
                                incomingData.RemoveFirst();
                            }
                            ReadBMS(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (dataLine.Contains("REL")) // received reply about relay turning on or off.
                {
                    if (dataLine.Contains("RELS")) // all relays turning on/off
                    {
                        if (dataLine.Contains("ON"))
                        {
                            for (int pin = 1; pin <= 4; pin++)
                            {
                                test.contactors[pin] = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else // "OFF"
                        {
                            for (int pin = 1; pin <= 4; pin++)
                            {
                                test.contactors[pin] = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else // single relay is turning on/off
                    {
                        int index = dataLine.IndexOf("REL");
                        int pin = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(dataLine[index + 3]);

                        if (dataLine.Contains("ON"))
                        {
                            test.contactors[pin] = true;
                        }
                        else if (dataLine.Contains("OFF"))
                        {
                            test.contactors[pin] = false;
                        }
                        else if (dataLine.Contains("GET"))
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(incomingData.First()) == 1)
                                test.contactors[pin] = true;
                            else
                                test.contactors[pin] = false;
                            incomingData.RemoveFirst();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Main timer used to log the duration of the test, calculate amp hours
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test.duration = ++tickCounter;

        // calculate Ah
        test.ampHoursOut = (test.ampHoursOut * 3600 + test.amperage * 1) / 3600;

        //read & output v, a, bms state
        //sendToController("CH1.GETANALOG"); // get voltage
        sendToController("CH2.GETANALOG"); // get amperage
        sendToController("CH3.GET"); // get BMS state

        //read & output temperature
        sendToController("CH4.GETTEMP"); // get temperature
        sendToController("CH5.GETTEMP");
    }
```

Comment: Props for the keen thinking on your skills ;) I am still struggeling to imagine your scenario/setup - so that it makes sense to me - to help ...

Comment: Some remarks: 1. Use a `Stopwatch` to measure time, the timer ticks won't be accurate. 2. A second is a long, long *long* time for a computer, that's not the problem. 3. Show how you manage your queue (best use a `BlockingCollection` for this).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Timers simply have a precision of somewhere close to 16 ms.  With an interval of 1 sec, and no problem with a margin of error of several milliseonds, that shouldn't be a problem in the slightest.

Comment: You need to show more code for us to be able to help. A 5-second delay sounds like something's blocking in your setup and processing can only happen when the block goes away for some reason. How do you update the UI? How do you protect your linked list?

Comment: @Servy why use a less accurate method when the better one is just as easy to implement? Those 16ms inaccuracies will add up in the long term.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski A `StopWatch` is a tool for measuring time elapsed, not executing code after a set period of time.  You'd have to do some sort of spinwait to use a stopwatch.  If you put the thread to sleep your precision becomes that of a `Timer`.

Comment: @Servy I think you misunderstood my point. The OP is measuring time by increasing a counter in the timer callback. I suggested him to use a `Stopwatch` instead, just for this task. I didn't say to drop the `Timer`.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Considering that he's measuring time in number of seconds, one would assume that being ~16 ms off wouldn't be a problem.  Since he's storing whole seconds he wouldn't even be able to store that increased precision, indicating that he likely has no need for it.  The precision he has is good enough.

Comment: I posted the full code to here: http://pastebin.com/AbRWh7f2 Thank you!

Comment: *Do not* use a `Timer` as a stopwatch. It's incredibly unreliable. If you want to know how long something takes, start a `Stopwatch`. See http://blog.mischel.com/2014/11/04/timers-dont-keep-track-of-time/

Comment: @JimMischel The Stopwatch class doesn't have an OnTimedEvent. If I am to perform a calculation ever second how would you suggest I do so?

Comment: @jules0075: Use the `Timer` for periodic events. Use the `Stopwatch` to count elapsed time. So start a `Stopwatch` *and* a timer. When you want to know how much time has elapsed, query the `Stopwatch.Elapsed` property. In your case, `test.Duration` should be equal to `Stopwatch.Elapsed`. Don't try to update it by counting timer ticks.

Comment: You should post a good code example _here_. Linked code may go out of date, and in any case it's too tempting for questioners to just dump _all_ the code to an external site rather than making a correct code example for SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I will note that it's not clear why you need either the timer or the worker. If no state changes until data is received, then IMHO you should only ever do other work in response to receiving data; that work can occur asynchronously -- i.e. start an async task to handle the work rather than blocking the receive event handler.

Comment: @JimMischel, thanks - will do that. 
To calculate AmpHours from Amps, I need to do a calculation every second (for high accuracy).
Still having the problem of my UI updating too late. I notice if I only poll for one sensor's data everything flows fine. Once I start polling for 2-4 sensors then the program slows down.

Comment: Figured out a solution that works. 

I was getting too much data from the sensors and my BackgroundWorker wasn't keeping up. I changed the code to only ask for sensor data when the queue of sensor data is below 5 items in length. 

If there is a way to make my processing more efficient, I would love to know it, and thank you for the stopwatch suggestion!